# Function to loop through a list of columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, list, function, loops

I'm trying to create a function or a loop in r that can loop through a list of columns for a specific string i.e '123', and create a new column with an indicator variable i.e 0 or 1 if the string is present in the defined columns.

Please see example below -
I would like to create a function/loop that will detect if the string '123' is found in any of the columns from df1 to df5, if the string is found then new_column will be 1, if not then it will be 0

```
  index df1 df2 df3 df4 df5 new_column
1     1 123 999 999 999 999          1
2     2 999 123 999 999 999          1
3     3 123 999 999 999 999          1
4     4 999 999 999 999 999          0
5     5 999 999 123 999 999          1
6     6 999 999 999 999 999          0
```

Comment: `df$new_column <- rowSums(df[,2:6] == 123)` or `"123"` if you actually have strings of numbers. Multiple occurrences will get added on, so add `> 0` and convert to numeric if that's possible.

Comment: @alistaire Both `123` and `"123"` should work: if they have `character`s, R will implicitly coerce `123` to `"123"`.

Comment: @nicola Oops, yeah; for some reason I lack confidence in infix operators to coerce like I want, but it's in the docs: `?Comparison`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (make sure 123 is `numeric`):

```
df <- cbind(df,new_c = sapply(1:length(df),function(x) ifelse(123 %in% df[x,],1,0)))

> df
  index df1 df2 df3 df4 df5 new_c
1     1 123 999 999 999 999     1
2     2 999 123 999 999 999     1
3     3 123 999 999 999 999     1
4     4 999 999 999 999 999     0
5     5 999 999 123 999 999     1
6     6 999 999 999 999 999     0
```

data:

```
> df
  index df1 df2 df3 df4 df5
1     1 123 999 999 999 999
2     2 999 123 999 999 999
3     3 123 999 999 999 999
4     4 999 999 999 999 999
5     5 999 999 123 999 999
6     6 999 999 999 999 999
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Reduce` with `|`

```
df$new_column <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[2:6], `==`, 123)))
```